# navCtrl ionic 3 invalid link

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm trying navegate for the ionic app but I don't know why the links are not working. Any idea? The app is developed in Ionic 3

**Error"Uncaught (in promise); invalid link: HomePage**

> help.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="box blue">
                <img src="assets/imgs/x.png" (click)="goToHome()" />
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

> help.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HelpPage } from './help';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelpPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild('HelpPage')
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    HelpPage
  ],
  exports: [
    HelpPage
  ]
})
export class HelpPageModule {}
```

> help.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, IonicPageModule, Platform, Slides, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-help',
  templateUrl: 'help.html'
})
export class HelpPage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  constructor(private platform:Platform, public navCtrl: NavController){}

  goToHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove single quote from     this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
 i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your home directory contain home.module.ts? Looks like you need to declare that 'HomePage' is an IonicPage by declaring @IonicPage() just before @Component, something along lines of

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: 'home-page.html',
})
export class HomePage {
//your HomePage logic goes here
    constructor(){}
}
```

Then you will have to create **home-page.module.ts** file in your 'home' directory

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Reload the project and try again

Answer (score 0):

in your app.module.ts did you add HomePage?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,NavController}from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewmapPage } from '../viewmap/viewmap';
@IonicPage({name: 'page-dash-board',
segment: 'my-dash-board'})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dash-board',
  templateUrl: 'dash-board.html',
})
export class DashBoardPage {
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
  {
    this.go();
  }
  go(){
  this.navCtrl.push(ViewmapPage);
  }
}
```